# polymorphic in place re-construction in C++ and/or clone pattern

Tags: c++, dynamic, constructor, destructor, polymorphism

I am trying to do the following trick:

```
class A {
    virtual ~A();
    virtual void reset() {
        this->~A();
        construct(); // this should magically use placement-new of the derived type on 'this', so that if called from an A pointer to a B class, it works.
    }

 };

 class B : public A {
     ...
 };
```

how would you implement construct in the most generic way you can?

I want to work with the existing default constructor, this is a change I am adding to an existing heirarchy. I am currently considering two options:

1) construct() is implemented in every derived class and is a call to a placement new.

2) move all constructors to an init() function in each class. This is counter intuitive to how we work, and may also cause a mess with things that can only be initialized with an initializer list.

Comment: This won't work since you can't assume that v-table pointer is still valid after object destruction (IIRC each destructor sets it to the currently destructed class, though it's probably compiler specific). Just implement reset() in the derived classes instead.

Comment: @JarkkoL, I can define a virtual function which returns a lambda with the constructor call, call that function BEFORE destruction, then do destruction, and then call the returned lambda.

Comment: @tohava: You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Or said differently, you are asking how to implement the wrong solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"How would you implement construct in the most generic way you can?"*

```
struct AA {
    virtual void reset() = 0;
    virtual ~AA() {}
};

template<class Derived>
class A : public virtual AA {
              // ^^^^^^^ prevent nasty problems introduced with eventually 
              //         multiple occurrence of AA in the inheritance hierarchy
public:
    virtual ~A();
    // No construct() necessary
    virtual void reset() {
        // Have an appropriate default constructor and assignment operator,
        // the latter is the equivalent for cloning
        static_cast<Derived&>(*this) = Derived();
    }
 };

 class B : public A<B> {
     // ...
 };
```

Usage

```
 B b;
 AA* vp = &b;

 vp->reset();
```

---

Two more points:

1. Never call destructors explicitly: `this->~A();`, this calls for trouble
2. Be careful with placement `new()`, not only it won't work for your case, it rarely does what people usually intend.

Comment: I like the CRTP, although it is not much more generic than forcing people to write a function that calls the default constructor with no parameters. I am afraid that the CRTP will confuse people here, but I agree it is a good solution.

Comment: @tohava I've changed the sample a bit. But you're right, it boils down forcing the implementers to provide default constructor and assignment operator. Though these are provided by the compiler by default, if no other constructor signatures are specified.

Comment: I've decided to use your version with placement-new. I'm marking you as correct.

Comment: ... except that you completely broke the original problem. Now `A` is not an interface that different derived types have. You cannot have two different `Derived` types, it has to be 1 derived... If this is truly the answer, then the question is quite misleading...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas One could easily introduce an interface for `reset()`. I've considered to show this, but left over 'til now. Do you think this should be shown? Also feel free to edit if you like.

Comment: The issue is that the OP is not clear on what the problem to solve is. In the general case, you would have to (as others suggest) provide a 'reset' virtual function, and the most derived type could opt to use CRTP with a different base to get the implementation (or just implement reset itself, which is a simpler solution). That is, if `A` is anything other than a generalized `reset`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas _'The issue is that the OP is not clear'_ Well, agreed! I've also been wondering, what they finally do with the replacement `new()` in conjunction with the CRTP :-S. @_MadScienceDreams mentioned a number of points, why all this attempt is questionable at all (that's why I upvoted their answer).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Edited a bit for clarification. But the XY-problem issue still stands of course.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents,(though pi's answer is more direct to your question) a class should do one thing and one thing alone. In general, you should separate your memory management and the class implementation. And what you are trying to do is compress down a call.

The most direct way to get the same functionality is to just use a bloody unique pointer (C++11).

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a(new B());
a.reset(new B());//deletes the old B and makes a new B.
```

This is OK if you can get away with non-contiguous memory allocation (and pro-tip, you almost always can). But lets say you can't (because its against your religion or whatever). Well, this will do almost exactly what your trying to do above.

```
 B a;//old reference
 a = B();//Reset!
```

This behaves exactly like the "in place" reset call you wrote, without any of the nasty side effects.

All of these methods have a common flaw. You have to give up the resources of the old reference to assume the resources of the new references. There is no reuse there, which is a shame. The only way to get around that is to provide a manual "reset" function. Classes in the STL do this with the "assign" function, and typically support more than just the default constructor.

```
 std::vector<int> x(100);//made a vector x of 100
 x.assign(50);//acts like x=std::vector<int>(50), but will most likely reuse the memory
```

Which is what PI was getting at with his CRTP response: was it does is static inheritance, I.E. it enforces a reset function without the penalties of polymorphism.

Comment: What you propose using `std::unique_ptr`, would even work well with the good old `std::auto_ptr` for this case (most of the time I imagine these being equivalent mind-internally).